# DBD::Oracle insert sydate instead of null

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I try to insert null values into date fields in Oracle from perl, but instead of null values it ends up inserting sysdate. When I do the same from sqlplus, it inserts the null values.

My code (just the important part)

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(ORA_RSET);

...

eval {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
         INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
             (VAL1, VAL2, VAL3, ENTRY_DATE, PROCESSED_DATE)
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)});
    my $rv = $sth->execute($VAL1, $VAL2, $VAL3, undef, undef);
    $insert_counter++;
};
if ( $@ ) {
    $FILE_PROCESS_STATUS = FILE_INVALID;
    logg("e", "$@");
}
if ( $FILE_PROCESS_STATUS = FILE_VALID ) {
    $dbh->commit;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you check how PHP handles nulls values. What is done here is that PHP is adding bind variables or placeholders to the query. The use of `undef`- are you sure PHP passes `null` value for `undef` to a date field?

Comment: Is it same when `""` instead of `undef`?

Comment: Rachcha: As it is mentioned in the description and tags, it is perl, not php. :)

mpapec: based on the documentation of DBD::Oracle I have to use undef as it is the null.
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Perl#DBD::Oracle_and_NULL_values

Comment: Can you please provde the example of SQL*Plus execution (full stack of insert statement and the result of selection after this). Also it's wirth th provide table definition DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DBI->trace` to log actions and actually see the statement that is being prepared.
See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885561/dump-prepared-sql-query-from-dbi-statement-in-perl).  This should show you if an incorrect SQL query is being created.

However, I would be willing to bet that the problem is something other than what you think it is.  Use the debugger to verify that *this piece of your code* is really causing the problem, or create a simple example script to test whether this is actually the problem.

Comment: This is very useful dan, I will follow your suggestions and will be back with the results.

Comment: It's a shame, but I modified the code at the wrong place. I made a simple script, which was working, than I realized, that I am modifying the wrong branch. Sorry and thank for the help to everyone especially to you dan :)