# DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 181 bind variables when 172 are needed

Tags: mysql, perl, bioinformatics

I am getting this error

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 181 bind variables when 172 are needed at line 110, <$fh> line 1.
```

I think the problem lies within this section of the code

```
while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {

    chomp $row;

    my @DNA = split('\|', $row);  

    my $participant_id = $DNA[0];
    $participant_id =~ s/\>//g;

    my $array = $DNA[1];

    my $length = length $array;

    $array =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    $array =~ s/(...)/$1 /g; 
    $array =~ s/\s+/,/g;

    my @DNA1 =   split (',', $array);
    unshift @DNA1, $participant_id;

    $sth4->execute(@DNA1);  # Line 110  
}

$sth4->finish;
```

Comment: Useful error message.  Your `@DNA` has more columns than the corresponding SQL statement knows about.  Find where the SQL statement is defined ( look for $sth4 further up in the code ), and see if you can figure out what to do.  You probably need to change the SQL to accommodate your data size.

Comment: You can see what SQL it is trying to run by turning on tracing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885561/dump-prepared-sql-query-from-dbi-statement-in-perl

Comment: Thanks @xxfelixxx, this gives me something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

With 172 placeholders I assume the SQL statement has been produced automatically

You need to look at the code around something like

```
my $sth4 = $dbh->prepare(...);
```

which contains 172 placeholders `?` whereas your statement

```
my @DNA1 = split (',', $array);
```

results in `@DNA1` having 181 elements

The problem is in these lines

```
$array =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
$array =~ s/(...)/$1 /g; 
$array =~ s/\s+/,/g;
```

which clearly don't do what you think they do

Show the contents of `$array` (in a new question) and describe the transformation that you really need and we will be able to help

By the way, those are some awful variable names. `$array` is clearly not an array, and `@DBA1` is just some .. database list .. thing, and has capital letters for no good reason